# UltiSnips not triggering correctly

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-plugin, ultisnips

I'm using UltiSnips.

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715

Everything works. Let's say when I type `st<tab>` it inserts `submit_tag…`. But if `st<tab>` is in between other characters, it won't work.

For example: `foost<tab>bar`

Anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 22):

I am the author of Ultisnips. You might get faster feedback on our bug tracker for things like this: github.com/SirVer/ultisnips.

The feature you are looking for is called inword expansion. Use it like this:

```
snippet st "My cool st snippet" w
stollen
endsnippet
```

The 'w' will make sure your snippet is also expanded inside of other words.

Comment: I can't find any mentioning of inspansion in the [README](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~sirver/ultisnips/github_mirror/view/head:/README.rst). The README (part 4.1) says that that is the default behavior without providing an option. Anyway, thanks for responding to this person's question. I'm very grateful for Ultisnips, I use it every day. Thanks for all the work you have put into it.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by inspansion. Maybe the i or w options? See the docs for this: https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/master/doc/UltiSnips.txt#L602

Comment: Wow, I provided the wrong link AND I somehow interpreted 'inword expansion' as 'inspansion' : s. I'm sorry!

Comment: Looks like that launchpad link is hardly the place for UltiSnips questions, either. Go to their github instead: https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips